# What is a good way of automatically checking HDDs health

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, raid, smartctl

I just configured a raid5 server setup containing three hdds `/dev/sda` `/dev/sdb` `/dev/sdc`

What is a good practice unix way of automatically checking the health of these drives and alerting the admin if any annomalies / disk crasch comes up?

The purpose is to give a warning, leaving time for ordering a new disk before they malfunction, minimizing downtime.

Comment: How about smartctl + cron + email?

Comment: @user1794469 Yes, I thought of it aswell, didn't know if it was a good way, but I'll try. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**That's exactly what the `smartd` daemon from the smartmontools package is for.**

Just install and enable it, and it will by default monitor all the hard drives in the machine and send an e-mail to `root` if SMART signals an issue of some sort. You can also configure it to run periodic SMART self-tests on the drives.

Just make sure that mail for `root` is forwarded to some mailbox that you actually read, so that you get the notification in time. (But that's good practice anyway, or you would never get any cron output for example.)

Comment: Good tip! Exactly what I was looking for. I now configured it to run a custom script when errors are found!